# Spark scala:-Getting error the way i am trying to use if statement within reduceByKey

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

In bellow program i am trying to use if statement within `reduceByKey` but getting error.

Bellow is my data which contains userid , shopname and rating:-

```
UserId ShopName  Rating
192     FBB        3.5
192     Reliance   4.9
192     Soch       2.0
20      Reliance   5.0
20      FBB        4.0
301     Soch       2.6
301     W Printed  3.9
```

Question:

**Find those shopnames which have not got ratings below 4 by any user. Answer should be shop Reliance as it has not got rating bellow 4 by any user.**

Bellow is my code:

```
val rdd=sc.textFile("Filepath\shoprating.dat")
val shop_rating=rdd.map(i=>i.split(" ")).map(i => (i(1),i(2).toDouble))

val GB_shop=shop_rating.groupByKey()

val Shopnames = GB_shop.reduceByKey((x, y) => if(x._2>=4 && y._2>=4)x )

Shopnames.collect
```

But the way i am using if statement inside `reduceByKey` is not working. So pls help me with the code.what exactly i need to do to get correct output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two issues here:

1. You're calling `x._2` assuming `x` is a tuple, but in fact it's an `Iterable[Double]` because you call `reduceByKey` on the result of `groupByKey` which groups values of the same key into an iterable. I don't think you need `groupByKey` here at all.
2. The function passed to `reduceByKey` must have a return value - so if you use an `if`, you'd need an `else` expression. Without it, the return type of this function is inferred to be `Any` which won't be useful. If you want to *remove* some of the keys, you'll have to use an RDD method that *filters* results, e.g. `filter` - "not returning a value" is not a valid way to remove entries from an RDD

A solution that overcomes both these issues is:

```
val Shopnames: RDD[String] = shop_rating
  .reduceByKey(math.min)
  .filter { case (name, minRating) => minRating >= 4.0 } // or .filter(_._2 >= 4.0)
  .keys
```

We reduce by key using the `min` method, keeping only lowest rating for each shop.
Then we filter out shops with min rating < 4, and discard the minimal ratings using `.keys` to get shop names only.

---

NOTE: there's an alternative for using `filter` and then `keys` - using `collect(f: PartialFunction)` which expects a partial function and returns the results of that function only for records for which it is defined:

```
val Shopnames: RDD[String] = shop_rating
  .reduceByKey(math.min)
  .collect { 
    case (name, minRating) if minRating >= 4.0 => name
  }
```

Note that this `collect` function has little to do with the `collect()` function that collects the RDD into a local array. The names are confusingly similar but the two are unrelated.